# why asterisk always make video calls when videosupport=yes?

Tags: asterisk

Asterisk will always make video calls to called user, even if the calling user actually make a voice call (asterisk will add sdp video media automatically to called party). The problem is that i need to translate this call to 3G users, but i don't know whether it is a normal voice call or video call.

Now I use asterisk v 1.8

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add code to your post if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk not do video call by default. It even can't initiate video call at all, just can support/bridge it

But softphone or hardphone you use as endpoint CAN do any type of call.

So you have consult your endpoint documentation or use other endpoint.

Comment: when I used my softphone on another sip server it worked by separate voice and video call.

Comment: Use tcpdump, check sip traces and see difference. After that come back, i will say how get same diff. But very likly other server just filter video codec on first invite. You can do same by excluding codec from peer description.